Transparent Shader makes transparent objects render on the lowest sorting layer when overlapping
I'm making a top down 2d game and I am using transparent sprites as shadows. But the problem I had was that shadows were overlapping and creating darker areas where they overlapped. To combat that I used a shader I had found online, but the problem is that the shader seems to render in reverse sorting order.
When it is just the 2 transparent objects the shader works and the darkness doesn't increase where they overlap:
enter image description here
And another object with a higher sorting layer is correctly rendered above the shadow:
enter image description here
And when the object has a lower sorting layer it correctly renders below the shadow:
enter image description here
But when 2 shadows which are on different sorting layers interact they seem to render on the lower of the 2 sorting layers, below the other object instead of the expected above:
enter image description here
Here is the shader, Do I need to modify the shader to make it work correctly or is there a alternative solution to this problem?
// Upgrade NOTE: replaced 'mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP,*)' with 'UnityObjectToClipPos(*)'

Shader "multiply2D"
{
    Properties
    {
        [PerRendererData] _MainTex ("Sprite Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Color ("Tint", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _MainTex ("Base (RGB), Alpha (A)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Stencil ("Stencil ID", Float) = 0
        _ColorMask ("Color Mask", Float) = 15
        _ClipAlpha ("ClipAlpha", Float) = 0.2
    }

    SubShader
    {
        Tags
        {
            "Queue"="Transparent"
            "IgnoreProjector"="True"
            "RenderType"="Transparent"
            "PreviewType"="Plane"
            "CanUseSpriteAtlas"="True"
        }

        Stencil
        {
            Ref [_Stencil]
            Comp NotEqual
            Pass Replace
        }

        Cull Off
        Lighting Off
        ZWrite Off
        ZTest [unity_GUIZTestMode]
        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
        ColorMask [_ColorMask]

        Pass
        {
        CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"
            #include "UnityUI.cginc"

            struct appdata_t
            {
                float4 vertex   : POSITION;
                float4 color    : COLOR;
                float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float4 vertex   : SV_POSITION;
                fixed4 color    : COLOR;
                half2 texcoord  : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 worldPosition : TEXCOORD1;
            };

            fixed4 _Color;
            fixed4 _TextureSampleAdd;
            fixed _ClipAlpha;

            v2f vert(appdata_t IN)
            {
                v2f OUT;
                OUT.worldPosition = IN.vertex;
                OUT.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(OUT.worldPosition);

                OUT.texcoord = IN.texcoord;

                #ifdef UNITY_HALF_TEXEL_OFFSET
                OUT.vertex.xy += (_ScreenParams.zw-1.0)*float2(-1,1);
                #endif

                OUT.color = IN.color * _Color;
                return OUT;
            }

            sampler2D _MainTex;

            fixed4 frag(v2f IN) : SV_Target
            {
                half4 color = (tex2D(_MainTex, IN.texcoord) );
                color.rgb=_Color.rgb;
                color.a*=_Color.a;
                clip (color.a - _ClipAlpha);
                return color;
            }
        ENDCG
        }
    }
}

I have tried some other shaders I have found Online but as I'm not at all familiar with shaders I don't know where I would even start
